# Derivation of the process noise covariance matrix for non linear system in UKF

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters, non-linear, unscented-kalman-filter

I have a continuous (in time) non-linear system in the form $\dot{x}=f(x(t)) + Bu(t) + w(t)$ which I would like to track with a UKF. $w(t)$ represent white noise (in particular, the acceleration and angular acceleration component of the dynamic system), $u(t)$ the known input, f(x(t)) the non-linear continuous function that decribes the motion of the system.

The procedure for the UKF is pretty clear, apart from the derivation of the Q matrix (covariance of the process noise).

I have seen on books (such as "estimation  with applications to tracking and navigation" by Bar-Shalom et al.) the process of finding $Q$ in case of continuous white noise model, with an already discretized system, not from a continuous non-linear transfer function.
The most relevant literature I have find for my case is the paper by Svensson "Derivation of the discrete-time constant turn rate and acceleration motion model", in which he gives the expression for the time discrete covariance $Q_k$:
[image: process noise covariance for ctra]

In which

- $\tilde{Q}_{CTRA}=\Gamma Q_{CTRA} \Gamma^T$, with $Q_{CTRA}$ is the continuous white noise covariance and $\Gamma$ is the noise gain;
- $f'_{CTRA}$ is the gradient of the continuous non-linear prediction function (motion model)

What I would like to understand is:

1. How may I derive the expression of $Q^k_{CTRA}$ here above?
2. How can I derive the expression of $Q^k_{CTRA}$ for a piecewise constant white noise (as opposed to continuous as in the expression here above)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: In the [Svensson paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8916654), he gives a reference to the five different methods to derive the process noise for the discrete model, which can be found [here (Chapter 12.3)](https://www.studentlitteratur.se/kurslitteratur/teknik-datorer-it-och-bygg/signalbehandling/statistical-sensor-fusion-33373-03/). However, Svensson does not the any of the suggested methods but the one described [here (Appendix A.8)](https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/cup_book_online_20131111.pdf).